# Make iframe not to reload at page refresh

Tags: iframe, html, reload

Is there any way to make div or an iframe not to reload at page refresh?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your iframe to avoid caching:

```
<head>
<meta http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
<meta http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
<meta http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

normal scenerio is Refreshable part should be in div/iframe. you shoud follow that,
there is no way what you are trying to do...